# PyGame collision response bug

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, collision

**My problem:**

When I am handling collision response in PyGame everything works fine until I collide with something diagonaly (xvel and yvel != 0). If I have a print("x") and print("y") statement when checking for their respective axis I get something like this:

[image]

It's clear that the bug is caused by the kinda random "x" in the middle there which causes the code to act as if the character collided with something on the x axis when in fact it was the y axis. So that is my question really, why does this happen?

Here is my collision response function:

```
def collide(self, direction):

    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, all_sprites_wall, False, rectconverter)
    if direction == "x":
        if hits:
            print("x")
            if self.vx > 0:
                self.hitboxrect.right = hits[0].hitboxrect.left
                self.x = self.hitboxrect.right - self.rect.width - camera.camera.x
            if self.vx < 0:
                self.hitboxrect.left = hits[0].hitboxrect.right
                self.x = self.hitboxrect.left - self.rect.width + self.hitboxrect.width - camera.camera.x
            self.rect.x = self.x

    if direction == "y":
        if hits:
            print("y")
            if self.vy > 0:
                self.hitboxrect.bottom = hits[0].hitboxrect.top
                self.y = self.hitboxrect.bottom - self.rect.height - camera.camera.y
            if self.vy < 0:
                self.hitboxrect.top = hits[0].hitboxrect.bottom
                self.y = self.hitboxrect.top - self.rect.height + self.hitboxrect.height - camera.camera.y
            self.rect.y = self.y
```

The players update function:

```
def update(self):
    self.move("x")
    self.hitboxrect.x = self.x + camera.camera.x
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.collide("x")

    self.move("y")
    self.hitboxrect.y = self.y + camera.camera.y + self.rect.height - self.hitboxrect.height
    self.rect.y = self.y
    self.collide("y")
```

The players move function:

```
def move(self, direction):
    if direction == "x":
        self.x += self.vx * dt
    if direction == "y":
        self.y += self.vy * dt
```

Comment: what exactly happens when you get to x?

Comment: @oppressionslayer Here is a gif of what is happening: https://gyazo.com/62c53cc4f3a944c317a951c0f8ae14ea

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are right, decided to rewrite the question a bit clearer and forgot to deleted the other post, did it now, my bad!

Comment: @Rabbid76 added some more code that could be the problem, anything else I should add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Somehow I found the answer myself:**

The problem was in the fact that I was adding and subtracting the camera values, so by removing the cameras x and y values the bug disappeared. I am not really sure why this solved it to be honest but I will take it. Here is how the code looks now for anyone curious:

```
def collide(self, direction):
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, all_sprites_wall, False, rectconverter)
    if direction == "x":
        if hits:
            print("x")
            if self.vx > 0:
                self.x = hits[0].hitboxrect.left - self.rect.width
                self.hitboxrect.right = hits[0].hitboxrect.left
            if self.vx < 0:
                self.x = hits[0].hitboxrect.right - self.rect.width + self.hitboxrect.width
                self.hitboxrect.left = hits[0].hitboxrect.right
            self.rect.x = self.x
    if direction == "y":
        if hits:
            print("y")
            if self.vy > 0:
                self.y = hits[0].hitboxrect.top - self.rect.height
                self.hitboxrect.bottom = hits[0].hitboxrect.top
            if self.vy < 0:
                self.y = hits[0].hitboxrect.bottom - self.rect.height + self.hitboxrect.height
                self.hitboxrect.top = hits[0].hitboxrect.bottom
            self.rect.y = self.y
```